# How to exclude sensors from output?

Tags: linux, fedora, temperature, lm-sensors

There is a well known issue where certain chips will report temperature readings that are completely bogus (probably because there is no sensor at all connected). They will show in lm_sensors output though:

```
nct6798-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter

AUXTIN0:                   +26.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)
                                    (crit = +100.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:                    +8.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)
                                    (crit = +125.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:                   -11.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)
                                    (crit = +125.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                   +26.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)
                                    (crit = +100.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN4:                   +79.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  ALARM
                                    (crit = +100.0°C)
```

How is it possible to exclude/ignore these sensors?

I've tried adding this to /etc/sensors3.conf and /etc/sensors.d/nuvoton without luck:

```
chip "nct6798-*"
    ignore "AUXTIN0"
    ignore "AUXTIN1"
    ignore "AUXTIN2"
    ignore "AUXTIN3"
    ignore "AUXTIN4"
```

EDIT: If I stop the lm_sensors.service, a bunch of readings disappear from the `sensors` output. If I start it again, the readings I'm trying to ignore are back. Is the daemon configured differently?

Environment:

- Fedora 39 x86_64
- lm_sensors 3.6.0

Comment: When running `sensors -u`, what is displayed for your chip? See especially section 5.1 in [lm_sensors wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/lm_sensors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @harrymc's advice to check the output of `sensors -u`, I noticed there were several readings below each "AUXTIN*" entry:

```
AUXTIN3:
  temp6_input: 26.000
  temp6_max: 80.000
  temp6_max_hyst: 75.000
  temp6_crit: 100.000
  temp6_alarm: 0.000
  temp6_type: 4.000
  temp6_offset: 0.000
  temp6_beep: 0.000
```

So I changed the configuration to refer to these `temp*` values instead of `AUXTIN*`:

```
chip "nct6798-*"
    ignore temp3
    ignore temp4
    ignore temp5
    ignore temp6
    ignore temp7
```

And it worked!